# How to re-position a Bootstrap Popover after dynamic content insertion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically whenever I am loading a [Bootstrap Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) with an empty `content` option and inserting content into it dynamically, the popover loses its correct position.

**For example:**

```
$('td.chartSection').each(function () {
    var $thisElem = $(this);
    $thisElem.popover({
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        container: $thisElem,
        delay: {
            hide: 500
        },
        content: ' '
    });
});

//After popup is shown, run this event
$('td.chartSection').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    var $largeChart = $(this).find('.popover .popover-content');

    //Insert some dummy content
    $largeChart.html("dfjhgqrgf regqef  f wrgb wrbgqwtgtrg <br /> wfghjqerghqreg fbvwqbtwfbvfgb <br />efgwetrg");
});
```

**My Question:**

Is there a method that can recalculate the popovers position such as `$('td.chartSection').popover('recalculate')`.

Or is there another way to re-position the popover without manually doing this with CSS styles?

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MUTr/2/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't a recalculate and there's really no easy way to do it.  That said, you can dynamically inject the popovers this way:

```
$('td.chartSection').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var myPopOverContent = 'This is some static content, but could easily be some dynamically obtained data.';
    $(this).data('container', 'body');
    $(this).data('toggle', 'popover');
    $(this).data('placement', 'top');
    $(this).data('content', myPopOverContent);
    $(this).popover('show');
});

$('td.chartSection').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Just replace all of your js in your fiddle with the above and check it out...

Comment: If you want to add html inside the content/body of the popover, this is the easiest way to do it. But you need to set that option: $(this).data('html', true); and obviously put the html into myPopOverContent

Answer (score 34):

Using Bootstrap v3.3.7:

You can extend the Popover constructor to add support for a re-positioning function. You can place this script below where you load bootstrap.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/e90npd0v/5/)

```
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.reposition = function () {
        var $tip = this.tip()
        var autoPlace = true

        var placement = typeof this.options.placement === 'function' ? this.options.placement.call(this, $tip[0], this.$element[0]) : this.options.placement

        var pos = this.getPosition()
        var actualWidth = $tip[0].offsetWidth
        var actualHeight = $tip[0].offsetHeight

        if (autoPlace) {
            var orgPlacement = placement
            var viewportDim = this.getPosition(this.$viewport)

            placement = placement === 'bottom' &&
                pos.bottom + actualHeight > viewportDim.bottom ? 'top' : placement === 'top' &&
                pos.top - actualHeight < viewportDim.top ? 'bottom' : placement === 'right' &&
                pos.right + actualWidth > viewportDim.width ? 'left' : placement === 'left' &&
                pos.left - actualWidth < viewportDim.left ? 'right' : placement

            $tip
                .removeClass(orgPlacement)
                .addClass(placement)
        }

        var calculatedOffset = this.getCalculatedOffset(placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight)

        this.applyPlacement(calculatedOffset, placement)
    }
})
</script>
```

Then in your script whenever you need to reposition your tooltip after inserting content. You can just call:

```
$element.popover('reposition')
```

Comment: I was hoping this one would work, but it seems if the dynamic content is too different from the original content then it doesn't actually reposition properly. https://jsfiddle.net/e90npd0v/9/

Comment: @KSib I fixed your JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e90npd0v/12/ because the reposition was not triggered at all.

Comment: This is the better solution, no flickering. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this is great.  I'll create similar function for Bootstrap 2 below.

Comment: This is a great solution because it works for popovers with dynamic content. It doesn't rebuild popovers destroying the dynamic content, but simply moves them around.

Answer (score 9):

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

This works for me.

Comment: This is the only solution that seems to work with ReactJS

Answer (score 8):

I just called

`button.popover('show');`

And it re-positioned it.

Comment: This does indeed work but makes the popover flicker as its gets hidden and shown again every time you trigger this.

Comment: Yes, this solution works for simple cases where popovers don't have dynamically generated content.  And it also flickers.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar situation where I had a popover which already contained some HTML (a loading spinner) and I was changing the content when an ajax call returned. In my ajax callback function, this was the code I used to change the positioning so it remained centred:

```
var originalHeight = $(popover).height();

$(popover).find('.popover-content').html(data);

var newHeight = $(popover).height();
var top = parseFloat($(popover).css('top'));
var changeInHeight = newHeight - originalHeight;

$(popover).css({ top: top - (changeInHeight / 2) });
```

Comment: Works great, but I removed the dividing part in the last line (changeInHeight / 2), so I end up with: `$(popover).css({ top: top - changeInHeight });`

Answer (score 4):

I used this code to adjust the height off the popover when it's already loaded to the page:

```
   var popover = $(this).closest('.popover');
   var sender = popover.prev();
   var adjustment = (sender.position().top - popover.height()) + 15;
   popover.css({ top: adjustment });
```

Variable sender is the target where the popover is centred from.

Answer (score 2):

this is inspired by @AlexCheuk answer above, but I needed a solution using **Bootstrap 2**.  Also, in my project I didn't need to change popovers' placement, so I cut that out.

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.reposition = function () {
        console.log('popover reposition is called');
        var $tip = this.tip();

        var placement = typeof this.options.placement === 'function' ? this.options.placement.call(this, $tip[0], this.$element[0]) : this.options.placement;

        var pos = this.getPosition();
        var actualWidth = $tip[0].offsetWidth;
        var actualHeight = $tip[0].offsetHeight;

        function getCalculatedOffset (placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight) {
            return placement == 'bottom' ? { top: pos.top + pos.height,   left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2 } :
                   placement == 'top'    ? { top: pos.top - actualHeight, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2 } :
                   placement == 'left'   ? { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left - actualWidth } :
                /* placement == 'right' */ { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left + pos.width };
        }

        var calculatedOffset = getCalculatedOffset(placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight);

        this.applyPlacement(calculatedOffset, placement);
        console.log(this);
    };
});
```

To call it:

```
$element.popover('reposition')
```

Comment: I have added some code for the "auto" placement which then gets the actual placement from the tip.
It works also for data-placement="auto left" when the actual placement of the popover is then set to right due to the position on the website.

Comment: if (placement.search('auto') >-1) {
            placement = $tip.hasClass('top') ? 'top' :
            $tip.hasClass('bottom') ? 'bottom' :
            $tip.hasClass('left') ? 'left' :
            $tip.hasClass('right') ? 'right' : 'auto';
            // console.log(['placement for auto', placement]);
        }

Answer (score 1):

If the popover's position is "top" (as in the question), you can just adjust its absolute positioning from the top of the page.

I've created a function to work out the height of the popover, and then shift it up on the page by its height.

```
function adjustPopoverHeight($popoverElement) {     
    var height = $popoverElement.height();
    var adjustment = 0 - height - 4;
    $popoverElement.css({ top: adjustment });
}
```

and use with an ajax request to get data:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(dat) { 
    //set the popover content to whatever you like

    //adjust height of popover
    var $popoverElement = $('.popover');
    adjustPopoverHeight($popoverElement);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the concept of jme11's answer and updated for Bootstrap 3.3.2+

```
$('button')
  .popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
  })
  .click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var popover_obj = $this.data('bs.popover');
    if (popover_obj.tip().hasClass('in')) {
      popover_obj.hide();
    } else {
      var opts = popover_obj.options;
      opts.content = $('<div/>').text('hello world');
      popover_obj.init('popover', $this, opts);
      popover_obj.show();
    }
  })
;
```

There's a method called setContent on the popover object, but for some reason it wasn't working for me. If you'd like to try, it would look like this:

```
popover_obj.setContent($('<div/>').text('hello world'));
```

Answer (score 0):

After a Popover content update, if you scroll up or down on page content, Popover does an auto-positioning and is readable again, so a simpler workaround to re-position the Popover after dynamic content update is to scroll down and up for 1 pixel on the page via **pure javascript**:

`var y = $(window).scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
$(window).scrollTop(y+1).scrollTop(y-1);`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced positioning issues after dynamically inserting other elements in the DOM and I solved them using the `container` option. By default my popovers were attached to `body`.

Attaching them to the closest container solved the position problems.

```
<div id="test">
    <span
        data-container="#test" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Help"
        data-trigger="hover" tabindex="-1" data-html="true"
        data-content="Some text">
</div>
```